# Sort hash by value and key (in that order)

Tags: perl, sorting, hash

I'm looking for a nice way to sort a hash in Perl by value first and by key afterwards.

Example:

```
 my %userids = (
  williams => "Marketing",
  smith    => "Research",
  johnson  => "Research",
  jones    => "Marketing",
  brown    => "Marketing",
  davis    => "Research"
);
```

Output:

```
Marketing: brown
Marketing: jones
Marketing: williams
Research: davis
Research: johnson
Research: smith
```

Please note that *value* was the first sorting level. Second sorting level is *key*. Any idea how to do this in an elegant and high-performance way? Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Good reference: http://www.misc-perl-info.com/perl-sort.html#shv

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my %userids = (
    williams => "Marketing",
    smith    => "Research",
    johnson  => "Research",
    jones    => "Marketing",
    brown    => "Marketing",
    davis    => "Research"
);

foreach (sort { ($userids{$a} cmp $userids{$b}) || ($a cmp $b) } keys %userids) 
{
    print "$_: $userids{$_}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I would like to add one more thing, use `\L sequence` in sorting.

From **Perlfaq4**: How do I sort a hash (optionally by value instead of key)?

To make our report order case-insensitive, we use the `\L sequence` in a double-quoted string to make everything lowercase. The `sort()` block then compares the lowercased values to determine in which order to put the keys.

```
foreach (sort { $userids{$a} cmp $userids{$b} or "\L$a" cmp "\L$b" )  {
    print "$_: $userids{$_}\n"; 
}
```

Output :

```
brown: Marketing
jones: Marketing
williams: Marketing
davis: Research
Johnson: Research # here 'J'ohnson, J is in uppercase(taking assumption), come as fifth record
smith: Research
```

2.

```
foreach (sort { $userids{$a} cmp $userids{$b} or $a cmp $b )  {
    print "$_: $userids{$_}\n"; 
}
```

Output:

```
brown: Marketing
jones: Marketing
williams: Marketing
Johnson: Research # here it shifted to fourth record
davis: Research
smith: Research
```

Comment: I'd say that semantically that would _only_ make sense when entering elements into the hash. Otherwise you will get inexplicable results when the hash contains both Johnson and johnson. I.e. when sorting you can hardly go and say 'keys are equivalent' - by traditional definition, hash tables can't contain two equivalent keys

Comment: yes that's true keys will always be unique in hash, never contain two equivalent keys but you can see the difference in output.

Comment: I can see the difference in output. That's why I think it would be an odd thing to do: it violates the [principle of least surprise](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrincipleOfLeastAstonishment) in my view

Comment: Rarely can happen but I thought would be nice to add it :)