# Perl: Hash-sort by value and get the key

Tags: perl, hash

Is there some perl "magic" to iterate through a hash sorted by the values but get the key in the iteration?

Sort by X and get X is easy (keys, values) - as well as sort by key and get the value.

Thanks!

Comment: No magic. You have to get all key-value pairs, sort them by value (yourself, using the appropriate function) and then take the key from each pair you are interested in.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886872/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-get-a-key-with-the-highest-value-from-a-hash-in-perl?rq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791958/sort-hash-by-value-and-key-in-that-order?rq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972224/the-simple-way-to-sort-based-on-values-in-a-hash-in-perl?rq=1

Comment: @Thilo: You don't have to *"get all key-value pairs"*: they're already sitting there, nicely paired-up, in the hash of data.

Comment: @Borodin: I meant to say "you have to iterate over all the entries of the hash". No shortcut to that.

Answer (score 5):

```
my %hash = ( one => 'a', two => 'b', three => 'c', four => 'd' );
for my $k ( sort { $hash{$a} cmp $hash{$b} } keys %hash ) {
    print "$k: $hash{$k}\n";
}
__END__
one: a
two: b
three: c
four: d
```

Answer (score 3):

Please remember in future to give an *example* of your data, the required result, and the code that you've written together with an account of what is wrong with it.

As it stands your question is very vague, and I have had to make several assumptions which may or may not be wrong

It isn't "magical"; you simply have to write the appropriate `sort` block

This will sort the keys of `%hash` in ascending lexical order of their corresponding values

```
my @sorted_keys = sort { $hash{$a} cmp $hash{$b} } keys %hash;
```

You may also make use of `List::UtilsBy`, like this. It may be significantly faster than the simple `sort` technique, depending on your data

```
use List::UtilsBy 'sort_by';

my @sorted_keys = sort_by { $hash{$_} } keys %hash;
```